# Modify REST response in groovy

Tags: json, rest, groovy

This is my first post so I hope this is the right place to ask these questions.
I am currently configuring an REST API call. The result of the API call is consumed by an application that allows the API call to be configured in groovy. The application expects the results to be a JSONObject

I am calling the following URL:

https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/select?ontology=cl&fieldList=iri,label&q=ba&rows=1

with the following code:

```
        def rest = new grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder()
        def offset = (currentPage-1)*maxRows
        def url = 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/select?ontology=cl&fieldList=iri,label&q=ba&rows=1'
        def resp = rest.get(url)
        results = resp.json.response.docs
```

The API response looks as followed:

```
{
   "responseHeader":{
      "status":0,
      "QTime":0,
      "params":{
         "hl":"true",
         "fl":"iri,label",
         "start":"0",
         "fq":[
            "ontology_name: (cl)",
            "is_obsolete:false"
         ],
         "rows":"1",
         "hl.simple.pre":"<b>",
         "bq":"type:ontology^10.0 is_defining_ontology:true^100.0 label_s:\"ba\"^1000  label_autosuggest_e:\"ba\"^500 synonym_s:\"ba\" synonym_autosuggest_e:\"ba\"^100",
         "q":"ba",
         "defType":"edismax",
         "hl.simple.post":"</b>",
         "qf":"label synonym label_autosuggest_e label_autosuggest synonym_autosuggest_e synonym_autosuggest shortform_autosuggest iri",
         "hl.fl":[
            "label_autosuggest",
            "label",
            "synonym_autosuggest",
            "synonym"
         ],
         "wt":"json"
      }
   },
   "response":{
      "numFound":146,
      "start":0,
      "docs":[
         {
            "iri":"http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CL_1000349",
            "label":"basal cell of epithelium of bronchus"
         }
      ]
   },
   "highlighting":{
      "cl:class:http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CL_1000349":{
         "label_autosuggest":[
            "<b>basal</b> cell of epithelium of bronchus"
         ],
         "synonym_autosuggest":[
            "<b>basal</b> cell of bronchus"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

The results are presented to users in a dropdown menu. As retrieving only on of the fields (response.docs.iri for example) does not provide enough information for the users, I'd like to create a new field )or overwrite an existing one to end with something like:

```
response.docs.iri_new = response.docs.iri + '(' + response.docs.label + ')'
```

In the given example this would lead to something like: http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CL_1000349 (basal cell of epithelium of bronchus)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome.

While you can certainly modify JSON with Groovy, this sounds more like a presentation issue -- the application responsible for `presented to users in a dropdown menu` is probably in a better position to extract/combine/format the fields in an API response to be most useful to the end user.

Having said that, an `each` loop can add the combined field to all the elements in the `docs` array:

```
...
def results = resp.json.response.docs
def updated = results.docs.each{doc -> doc['iri_new'] = "${doc['iri']} (${doc['label']})"}
```

Full Log

```
groovy> import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
groovy> import groovy.json.JsonOutput 
groovy> apiresponse=''' 
groovy> { 
groovy>    "response":{ 
groovy>       "numFound":146, 
groovy>       "start":0, 
groovy>       "docs":[ 
groovy>          { 
groovy>             "iri":"http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CL_1000349", 
groovy>             "label":"basal cell of epithelium of bronchus" 
groovy>          }, 
groovy>          { 
groovy>             "iri":"another uri", 
groovy>             "label":"a good label" 
groovy>          } 
groovy>       ] 
groovy>    } 
groovy> } 
groovy> ''' 
groovy> slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(apiresponse) 
groovy> println "Before:" 
groovy> println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(slurped.response.docs)) 
groovy> updated = slurped.response.docs.each{doc -> doc['iri_new'] = "${doc['iri']} (${doc['label']})"} 
groovy> println "After:" 
groovy> println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(updated)) 
 
Before:
[
    {
        "iri": "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CL_1000349",
        "label": "basal cell of epithelium of bronchus"
    },
    {
        "iri": "another uri",
        "label": "a good label"
    }
]
After:
[
    {
        "iri": "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CL_1000349",
        "label": "basal cell of epithelium of bronchus",
        "iri_new": "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/CL_1000349 (basal cell of epithelium of bronchus)"
    },
    {
        "iri": "another uri",
        "label": "a good label",
        "iri_new": "another uri (a good label)"
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi,
unfortunately it's not possible to configure this within the application.
However, your solution works like a charm. Thank you very much!